# Diet plan review

Tags: diet, workout, food-preparation

I used to work out and got myself in shape then i was diagnosed with *hyperthyroid* and because of that my health went down and after that my *B12* level went down. Currently my immune system is weak and I want to start exercising at home for which I have a Calisthenics plan.

I made diet plan and there are some things which my doctor has advised me to not eat and they are :  *Wheat, sugar, dairy, peanut butter*.

I weigh 50 KG and my height is 5'9. Please take a look and review my diet plan and tell me how can I improve my diet to gain clean weight. 
Plan is as follows:

2 banana 1/2 hour before workout

Workout in morning

- Breakfast :  Oats with 2 eggs
- Any Fruit (berries, kiwi, apple, papaya, pineapple)
- Lunch : Quinoa with chicken breast and eggs
- Evening snack: 6-7 Almonds, 12-15 Walnuts and 2 banana
- Dinner: Chicken breast + eggs with any green vegetable (B12 1000mcg + Salmon fish oil capsule)

Edit: I do not want to take Whey protein as there is so much sugar in it in hidden forms. There are sugar free whey protein but either they are costly or of unestablished brands which I cannot trust.

Answer (score 1):

IANA dietitian or nutritionist, but I recommend:

1. Ensuring that you have a daily caloric surplus.
2. Consuming at least one gram of protein per pound of bodyweight, per day.
3. Consuming more fat, of which you appear to have very little in your diet.

You're very light for your height.  You probably could simply *double* your daily intake for some weeks.  In conjunction with barbell-based strength training, you would build muscle, fat, bone, etc., all of which you probably need.

Comment: What can I add for good fat?

Comment: @Totoro, what do you mean by "good fat"?  "Good" in what way(s)?  Perhaps ["Facts on fats: Dietary fats and health"](http://www.eufic.org/en/whats-in-food/article/facts-on-fats-dietary-fats-and-health) may help.